# Automated script to delete files, getting error : UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 13-16

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I'm writing a little script in Python3 to move files that are older than 31 days from my Downloads folder to another folder (so they can be deleted). As I have some files and folder that are in Russian and Arabic, I am getting the following error in the console :

```
File "C:\Users\mycomputer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 13-16: character maps to <undefined>
```

Here is my python code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, time, sys
import shutil
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

current_time = time.time()
days_old = 31              # Files that are 31 days old
days = (days_old*24*60*60) # We need to convert the number of days in seconds in order to use it within stat_time.atime
time_delete = current_time - days
source_path = "C:/Users/mycomputer/Desktop/python_move_temp/"
dest_path = "C:/Users/mycomputer/Desktop/python_moved_from_temp/"
logfile = "C:/Users/mycomputer/Desktop/python_moved_from_temp/" # Logging all the actions in the log file to see what happened


files_to_delete = []
for file in os.listdir(source_path):
    #print(os.stat(source_path+i).st_mtime, i, "was last modified on")
    #print(i, "- was last modified on ", os.stat(source_path+i).st_mtime)
    if os.stat(source_path+file).st_mtime < time_delete:
        # >> shutil.move(source_path+file, dest_path+file)
        files_to_delete.append(file)
        print("DELETING",file, time_delete) # Files that are going to be kept
print("Successfully deleted", len(files_to_delete), "file(s)")
```

I have tried many options, but I don't know how to get it work.

---

NOTE : I am still a begginer in Python, as I am still learning, the code might be awful or not well-written :)